# How do I create a zip file of a given compressed size in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, size, zip

I have a pile of records that need to be converted to XML then zipped up into a file, so I can send it on to a server that is expecting said records. 
The problem I have, is that the server can only accept files that are smaller than a given amount.. Lets say for argument sake 10 Megs

```
    require 'zip/zip'    
    Zip::ZipOutputStream.open("tmp/myfile_#{Process.pid}.zip") do |zos|
      i_xml.each_with_index do |xml, index|
        zos.put_next_entry("#{index}.xml")
        zos << xml
      end
    end
```

The code above creates the zip file perfectly.. but I don't see how I can get the compressed size.

I can give some lea-way for the zip header and stuff.. So once I can tell how big my output is, I could tinker. It's just getting that size seems not in the cards for this class.

Note: I've tried installing zipRuby because it's has a compressed size method, but that just leads me down another rabbit hole.. Native extensions and such.

Answer (score 0):

Can't see anything in the Zip library to do this, sorry.

Consider, if you can:

- pushing further with getting zipRuby to compile
- breaking the finished zip file into fixed-size chunks with simple File.read statements and putting the chunks back together at the server.
- limiting the size of the zip file by limiting the number of files added, e.g. add files until the file size limit is exceeded, then remove the last added file and add it to a new zip file

Comment: Yeah.. I've no problem with going over, I just short it.. say I got 10 megs, well I build for 9.5 and I'm safe.. But the problem I have is, how do I get the compressed file size in rails.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by putting the file back together at the server. I don't own the system where the files are going.

Comment: the zipRuby idea is perhaps my best option, but I don't even know where to start with the task.. There seems little in the way of guidance, for these issues. I will continue reading up on it..